# How to specify the file path for saving the audio file recorded with Pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

I'm trying to figure out a way to set a custom path of my local directory for the recorded file to be saved. Currently, the recording is saved inside my project directory, but I want to specify a different folder for it.

```
def record_audio():
filename =test 
chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
channels = 1
sample_rate = 16000
record_seconds = 5
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=channels,
                rate=sample_rate,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk)
frames = []
for i in range(int(sample_rate / chunk * record_seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    # stream.write(data)
    frames.append(data)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
st.write("Finished recording.")
wf = wave.open(filename, "wb")
# set the channels
wf.setnchannels(channels)
# set the sample format
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
# set the sample rate
wf.setframerate(sample_rate)
# write the frames as bytes
wf.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
# close the file
wf.close()
```

Comment: try to include the relative path in `filename` ?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as declaring a file variable and specifying the path, you can locate it whether you are using the command line on Windows as a CD or on UNIX as a PWD. Finally you declare it when writing the wav and that's it.

Like that:

```
var filepath: '/home/root/Projects/audios/filename.wav'

waveFile = wave.open(filepath, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(data)
waveFile.close()
```